# C++ VS 2019 Expected '}' Error but the code runs fine

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I've written this code using Visual Studio 2019 community version just for practice and I keep getting "expected '}'" error at the very last line of the code. When I click run, it runs fine. Why is that?

Here is the full code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void funSayHi();

class People
{
public:
    void callPeople(string x, int y, double z)
    {
        ResName = x;
        ResAge = y;
        ResHight = z;

        cout << ResName << endl << ResAge << endl << ResHight << endl;
    }

private:
    string ResName = "No Name";
    int ResAge = 0;
    double ResHight = 0;
};

int main()
{
    string name;
    int age;
    double hight;

    funSayHi();

    cout << "Enter name\n";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter age\n";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Enter hight\n";
    cin >> hight;

    People peopleObj;
    peopleObj.callPeople(name, age, hight);   
}

void funSayHi()
{
    cout << "Hi\n";
} //VS 19 underlines this bracket and says "expected '}'"
```

Comment: Code is ok - live - https://godbolt.org/z/r7jWEfvfY - probably just IntelliSense having an off day.

Comment: Sometimes intellisense gets messed up or another extension. Sometimes restart helps, or deleting .vs folder.

Comment: VS's intellisense parser is not the same parser as used by Microsoft's `CL.EXE` compiler/linker.